# Array of arguments to call m4 from bash

Tags: bash, m4

I'm trying to dynamically compute arguments to call `m4` with. But I can't get strings in quotes to work properly.

Im trying to call `m4 -DFOO="foo oh oh" sample.m4` with the following code:

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=(-DFOO="foo oh oh")
m4 ${args[@]} sample.m4
```

sample.m4:

```
foo is FOO
bar is BAR
```

When I run the m4 command manually it works fine. When i use my test script, I get the following error :

```
m4: cannot open `oh': No such file or directory
m4: cannot open `oh': No such file or directory
foo is foo
bar is BAR
```

Clearly, it's trying to open the words in the string as files. If I escape the quotes, I get this error :

```
m4: cannot open `oh': No such file or directory
m4: cannot open `oh"': No such file or directory
foo is "foo
bar is BAR
```

How do I get this to work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always quote your variable/array expansions unless you have a reason not to (which is never the case mostly)

```
m4 "${args[@]}" sample.m4
```

An unquoted expansion has caused the words in the array to be split and ended up getting unequal number of parameters to `m4` command.